# laravel sentry not update groups permissions entry in groups table

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, sentry

Currently I am reviewing a laravel project, using Sentry for authentication. Each routes will have a permission in groups table created by Sentry.

For example a row in groups tables, I am using mongodb

```
{
  "name": "Admins",
  "permissions": "{\"task1.create\":1,\"task1.edit\":1,\"task1.delete\":1}",
  "created_at": ISODate("2015-10-22T01:16:57.118Z"),
  "user_ids": [
    "547c2b5aabb1ce1752318f27",
    "54d82fa1e471f7cf438b4569",
  ]
}
```

when I adding new route in routes.php but Sentry did not update groups permissions

For example, I adding task2 the same as task1, and I want groups table look like

```
{
      "name": "Admins",
      "permissions": "{\"task1.create\":1,\"task1.edit\":1,\"task1.delete\":1,\"task2.create\":1,\"task2.edit\":1,\"task2.delete\":1}",
      "created_at": ISODate("2015-10-22T01:16:57.118Z"),
      "user_ids": [
        "547c2b5aabb1ce1752318f27",
        "54d82fa1e471f7cf438b4569",
      ]
    }
```

How can I do that, is there any command or something to update groups table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually update the group. You can create the page to update the permission.

Here is the pseudo code to update the group.

```
try
{
    // Find the group using the group id
    $group = Sentry::findGroupById(1);

    // Update the group details
    $group->name = 'Users';
    $group->permissions = array(
        'admin' => 1,
        'users' => 1,
    );

    // Update the group
    if ($group->save())
    {
        // Group information was updated
    }
    else
    {
        // Group information was not updated
    }
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\NameRequiredException $e)
{
    echo 'Name field is required';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupExistsException $e)
{
    echo 'Group already exists.';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e)
{
    echo 'Group was not found.';
}
```

For more check the manual : https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#example-8

Comment: Although it update groups table in database, but it not update in views. Does it cache somewhere?